# Correct picture path

Tags: reactjs, heroku, strapi

I have this  [site](https://lebraojohns.netlify.app)

(Gatsby and Strapi API deployed in Heroku). My problem is that I can't find the proper path to render the pictures.

Here is the [API](https://john-strapi.herokuapp.com/bands) and here is the [repo](https://github.com/jcgsr/ago-JohnPunkBandsList).

My code regarding the rendering of the pics:

```
  .map(band => (
        <article className="bands" key={band.id}>
          <h2>{band.band_name}</h2>
          <img
            src={band.band_img.name}
            alt={band.band_name}
          />
          <p>{band.band_desc}</p>
```

I've already replace **src={band.band_img.name}** to a number of things like:

band.band_img.**formats.thumbnail.url**

band.band_img.**url**

so on and so forth to no avail.

A friend of mine told me to create .env files

*uploads_path: /uploads/*      (.env.production)

and

*uploads_path: uploads/*      (.env)

I did and nothing.

Picture of *console.log(band.band_img)*

[image: console.log]

Please, any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does console.log(band.band_img) returns? You can look for the url in the obj

Comment: It seems the problem is in Heroku. Thank you.

Comment: https://lebraojohns.netlify.app The images now are displayed. Just so sum up the steps to achieve that based on the answers: a) deploy the Strapi API in/through Heroku: the [docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/heroku.html), or if you prefer a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1rEwMXK2z4&t=636s); b) Heroku really destroys/deletes the images when uploaded locally, so I set Cloudinary to serve them and connected it to Strapi following the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary); c) con

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the images are not being uploaded. If you look at the following images path, they won't be displayed (what you were trying so far):

- https://lebraojohns.netlify.app/static/uploads/thumbnail_badreligion_7007c2c028.jpeg
- https://lebraojohns.netlify.app/uploads/thumbnail_badreligion_7007c2c028.jpeg

I've tried looking at several paths but none of them worked for me.

You won't see any image so your code is not able to display anything at `band.band_img.name` with according to your API is where it should be:

```
band_img: {
  id: 7,
  name: "badreligion.jpeg",
  alternativeText: "",
  caption: "",
  width: 315,
  height: 160,
  formats: {
    thumbnail: {
      ext: ".jpeg",
      url: "/uploads/thumbnail_badreligion_7007c2c028.jpeg",
      hash: "thumbnail_badreligion_7007c2c028",
      mime: "image/jpeg",
      name: "thumbnail_badreligion.jpeg",
      path: null,
      size: 9.63,
      width: 245,
      height: 124
   }
}
```

*P.S: I love Bad Religion and all the bands*

Your code looks good as soon as you fix your image uploading/server issue the code should work alone.

The images that you have stored under `/src/assets` will be never accessible for your code (transpiled to the public folder) unless you use them in one component.

Depending on your specifications, you can bypass it by adding your images under the [`/static` folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/) to clone them into the public one.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understood everything. P.S.: there are over one hundred punk bands to be added as soon as I fix this issue.

Answer (score -1):

It's a problem with your server, for example the following should work:

```
const getBandImg = (band) => band.band_img?.formats?.url;
```

And to use it anywhere you want to get the img url:

```
  .map(band => (
        <article className="bands" key={band.id}>
          <h2>{band.band_name}</h2>
          <img
            src={getBandImg(band)}
            alt={band.band_name}
          />
          <p>{band.band_desc}</p>
```

Which you already tried with `band.band_img.formats.thumbnail.url`, but after taking a look at your website, I noticed that the images aren't reachable either in the API or the frontend, for example:

https://john-strapi.herokuapp.com/uploads/dri_6a22b5e947.jpeg
Doenst return the image

https://lebraojohns.netlify.app/uploads/dri_6a22b5e947.jpeg
Neither

So it is something you have to solve in your host, not a problem with gatsby

Comment: Thank you. I'll try finding the problem (possibly) in Heroku.